# Using a large 4K TV as 4 screens in MacOs

Tags: macos, tv

I am looking to buy a new TV to use it as a screen when I am smart working. I do not expect any particular connectivity problem, however I would like to split my screen in 4 desktops.

Is there anything I should keep in mind with MacOS?

Comment: What to keep in mind… well, if you find a way to actually achieve this, do let us know. I've never found anything that can do this.

Comment: @Tetsujin BSD doesn't allow extending the desktop like in Windows?

Comment: @JW0914 - not sure how to respond to that. macOS isn't BSD. macOS allows a lot of flexibility & options for Spaces/Mission Control/displays, but making one display into 4 simultaneous quadrant-by-quadrant Spaces isn't one of them. It can do left/right split-screen, but that's a kludge imo. Windows' extended display feature is quite primitive in comparison. Win 10's Virtual Desktops has improved this a bit - though I've no idea if it can split one display into 4 simultaneous Spaces; I didn't even think it has the concept of Spaces.

Comment: There's an article about what it can do here - https://community.windows.com/en-us/stories/virtual-desktop-windows-10 - but read all the comments underneath for what it can't do.

Comment: Are you saying that in 2021 I can’t smart work using a large TV as a replacement for two or three external screens ?

Comment: This is possible if you purchase a TV that supports displaying multiple inputs at once.  These are not common, nor are they cheap.  Plus you need to have a graphics card that supports the number of outputs needed.

Comment: @Keltari - good thought. I've never investigated displays designed to do this. I had vague thoughts of getting my own reasonably high-end 55" OLED TV to do this… but ran out of research avenues. There are Macs that can handle 6 displays - some officially, some unofficially - https://www.macrumors.com/2020/11/24/m1-macs-able-to-run-six-external-displays/ At the expensive end of the scale, the Mac Pro can run 6x 4k displays, the iMac Pro 4x 4k.

Comment: Any suggestion of such tvs @Keltari